# Is it possible to bootstrap a Diebold-Mariano test?

Tags: self-study, forecasting, bootstrap, volatility-forecasting, diebold-mariano-test

I am currently working on a small project where I want to use a (two-sided) 1-step ahead ($h=1$) Diebold Mariano test to compare forecast losses for different realized measures calculated on time-series data. However, my supervisor told me to use a stationary bootstrap with average block length of 10 in order to increase the quality of statistical-inference in the forecast comparison analysis.

Now, I'm wondering if I can use this bootstrap method on a Diebold-Mariano test (or if I should change the forecast comparison method entirely) and how I should proceed to do this?

Any help would be very much appreciated! :-)

Comment: Hi: This paper ( at the bottom ) is pretty relevant to your question.  I hope it helps. Briefly, the two approaches are really different.  If you want to do bootstrapping check out all of the Clark and Mcracken literature. https://www.sas.upenn.edu/~fdiebold/papers/paper113/Diebold_DM%20Test.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the paper. As you said, the two approaches are different, but I still can't see a valid reason (based on intuition or math) why you can't apply bootstrap to a DM-test. In this article/paper [link](https://econ.unc.edu/files/2018/10/MHFC2018.pdf), he finds a bootstrap method for the multi-horizon superior predictive ability (SPA), and further discusses that for a single horizon, the uniform SPA (uSPA) reduces to a simple Diebold-Mariano test statistic (p.11 bottom). So I thought that I could use his bootstrap implementation for a single $h$, (p. 13 top)?

Comment: Hi: I don't have time to read the paper at the link but my memory tells me the following ( which may only be half right ). There is no underlying model assumed when you apply the diebold-mariano test. Therefore, you can't do any bootstrapping because there is model to base the bootstrapping procedure on. The fact that the authors of your paper don't mention the 2nd DM paper hints that they  may not be aware of it. I'm not sure if you read it carefully but Diebold explains that their test is totally model independent. You could come up with forecasts in your head and the test is still valid..